# HTML canvas cursoring with grid

Tags: javascript

Now I'm struggling with a cursor in canvas.

I want to make a square following the cursor.

```js
const width=16;
function init(){
  const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', observe);

}

function observe(e){
  const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const {X,Y} = getPosition(e);
    ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(255,0,0,0.01)`;
    let newX=X-100, newY = Y-100;
    if(X-100 < 0){
      newX = 0;
    }else if(X-100 > 200){
      newX = 200;
    }
    if(Y-100 < 0){
      newY = 0;
    }else if(Y-100 > 200){
      newY =200;
    }
    //ctx.clearRect(0,0,400,400);
    ctx.strokeRect( newX,newY, 200, 200);

  }
  function getPosition(e:any){
    return {X: e.offsetX, Y: e.offsetY}
  }
    function drawBoard(){
  const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    for (var x = 0; x <= 400; x += width) {
        ctx.moveTo(0.5 + x + 0, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(0.5 + x + 0, 400 + 0);
    }

    for (var x = 0; x <= 400; x += width) {
        ctx.moveTo(0, 0.5 + x + 0);
        ctx.lineTo(400 + 0, 0.5 + x + 0);
    }
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(128,128,128,0.5)";
    ctx.stroke();
}
drawBoard();
init();
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="400px" height="400px" />
```

when I move the mouse on the canvas, they keep all my move.

I don't want to keep all of them.

so, I've found `clearRect()` but it removes all even the grid.

I want to keep my grid and remove the shadow of cursor.

Comment: You need to stack two canvases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options here:

1. Instead of drawing the box on the canvas, just use another DOM element styled appropriately. This is probably the simplest option.
2. Make two canvases, once with the box that you can refresh, and the other with your grid. Position them on top of one another. This is similar to #1, except you are using another Canvas a the DOM element.
3. Simply redraw the entire canvas. This is the least performant, but depending on your use case it may not be a significant issue.
4. Overwrite the old box with white, then find all of the intersecting grid lines and redraw them. This is obviously the most cumbersome/error prone, and you should definitely consider the other options instead.

Fundamentally with canvases, you are directly drawing on top of what is already there. This is fundamentally different than working with the DOM, where you can add/remove/move elements.

Answer (score 1):

I think because you have to set a global object that represents the rectangle and then in the mousemouse listener you just assign new coordinates that you recieve for the mouse in your global object, then in the drawing function just use the global object of the rectangle to draw it on the coordinates that you just saved, and before the drawing you need to clear the canvas every time. In my case i used `window.requestAnimationFrame` to do the animation loop because it's not running in the task queue so the animation is smooth.

Just one thing i saw in your case is your getting new canvas and context in every function call and that can be bad in performence, you set them as globals.

here is the code:

```js
const width = 16;
let posRect = {x:0, y:0};

function init() {
  canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', observe);
}

function observe(e) {
    let pos = getPosition(e);
  posRect = {x:pos.X, y: pos.Y};
}

function getPosition(e) {
  return {
    X: e.offsetX,
    Y: e.offsetY
  }
}

function drawBoard() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (var x = 0; x <= 400; x += width) {
    ctx.moveTo(0.5 + x + 0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(0.5 + x + 0, 400 + 0);
  }

  for (var x = 0; x <= 400; x += width) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0.5 + x + 0);
    ctx.lineTo(400 + 0, 0.5 + x + 0);
  }
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(128,128,128,0.5)";
  ctx.stroke();
  
  ctx.strokeStyle = `rgba(255,0,0,0.9)`;
  let newX = posRect.x - 100,
    newY = posRect.y - 100;
  if (posRect.x - 100 < 0) {
    newX = 0;
  } else if (posRect.x - 100 > 200) {
    newX = 200;
  }
  if (posRect.y - 100 < 0) {
    newY = 0;
  } else if (posRect.y - 100 > 200) {
    newY = 200;
  }
  ctx.strokeRect(newX, newY, 200, 200);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(drawBoard);
}

init();

drawBoard();
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="400px" height="400px" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stack two canvases on top of each other.

Just draw the grind once, on the bottom layer; and re-draw the cursor each time the mouse is moved.

```js
const cellSize = 16;
const cursorScale = 3.0;
const findLayer = (sel) => document.querySelector(sel).getContext('2d');

const layers = {
  top: findLayer('.top'),
  bottom: findLayer('.bottom')
};

Object.assign(layers.top.canvas, { width: 320, height: 160 });
Object.assign(layers.bottom.canvas, { width: 320, height: 160 });

drawBoard(layers.bottom);
layers.top.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

function onMouseMove(e) {
  drawCursor(layers.top, getPosition(e));
}

function getPosition(e) {
  return { X: e.offsetX, Y: e.offsetY }
}

function drawCursor(ctx, position) {
  const { X, Y } = position;
  const cursorSize = cellSize * cursorScale;
  const offset = cursorSize / 2;
  
  ctx.strokeStyle = `rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)`;
  let newX = X - offset, newY = Y - offset;
  if (X < offset) {
    newX = 0;
  }
  if (X > ctx.canvas.width - offset) {
    newX = ctx.canvas.width - cursorSize;
  }
  if (Y < offset) {
    newY = 0;
  }
  if (Y > ctx.canvas.height - offset) {
    newY = ctx.canvas.height - cursorSize;
  }
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.strokeRect(newX, newY, cursorSize, cursorSize);
}

function drawBoard(ctx) {
  for (var x = 0; x <= ctx.canvas.width; x += cellSize) {
    ctx.moveTo(0.5 + x + 0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(0.5 + x + 0, ctx.canvas.height + 0);
  }
  for (var x = 0; x <= ctx.canvas.height; x += cellSize) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0.5 + x + 0);
    ctx.lineTo(ctx.canvas.width + 0, 0.5 + x + 0);
  }
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5)";
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
.stacked {
  position: relative;
  /* Disable -> cursor: none; */
}

.stacked canvas {
  position: absolute;
  border: thin solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="stacked">
  <canvas class="bottom"></canvas>
  <canvas class="top"></canvas>
</div>
```